# After calling __getattr__ method

Tags: python, getattr

In Learning Python 3rd, I saw this code

```
class wrapper:
    def __init__(self, object):
        self.wrapped = object
    def __getattr__(self, attrname):
        print("Trace:", attrname)
        return getattr(self.wrapped, attrname)

x = wrapper([1,2,3])
x.append(4)
print(x.wrapped)
```

I want to know exactly what happens after calling this `__getattr__` method, which only returns the method by `getattr`.

Why is the result of the last line `[1, 2, 3, 4]`?

There is no code that execute the returned function with the original argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `wrapper` class does not have a `.append` attribute, so Python falls back to the `wrapper.__getattr__` method. From the [`object.__getattr__` special method documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__):

> Called when an attribute lookup has not found the attribute in the usual places (i.e. it is not an instance attribute nor is it found in the class tree for `self`).

The wrapped object (the list object with `[1, 2, 3]`) does have a `append` attribute (a method), so `getattr(self.wrapped, 'append')` returns it.

The returned method is called, passing in `4`, appending that to the `self.wrapped` list object.

You can easily reproduce the steps yourself:

```
>>> wrapped = [1, 2, 3]
>>> getattr(wrapped, 'append')
<built-in method append of list object at 0x107256560>
>>> getattr(wrapped, 'append')(4)
>>> wrapped
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: In short, python interpreter executes the returned function with original arguments after calling __getattr__ method ?

Comment: @q2ven: `__getattr__` is called first, which returns the method object, which then is called. The `x.append` part is handled first, and whatever that produces, is called with the `(4)` part of the expression.